# Consulta utilizando Hibernate não traz registro

Tags: java, query, hibernate

Estou tentando consultar no banco de dados HSQLDB utilizando o Hibernate porém não estou tendo sucesso.

Quando eu faço:

```
session.get(Usuario.class, new Integer(1));
```

É feita a consulta, pois mostra a query montada pelo Hibernate. Porém não traz registro algum, mesmo ele existindo no banco.

A query montada compara o ID do registro que eu preciso com um ponto de interrogação (`?`).

Essa é a consulta montada:

```
select usuario0_.ID as ID1_0_0_, usuario0_.NOME as NOME2_0_0_,
       usuario0_.EMAIL as EMAIL3_0_0_, usuario0_.SENHA as SENHA4_0_0_
from USUARIOS usuario0_ where usuario0_.ID=?
```

Abaixo estão algumas imagens que talvez sejam necessárias:

### LOCALIZAÇÃO DOS ARQUIVOS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### CONFIGURAÇÃO HIBERNATE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:EcoChat</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- Mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="ecochat/dao/modelos/usuario/mapeamento/usuario.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

### MAPEAMENTO USUÁRIO

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="ecochat.entidades.modelos.Usuario" table="USUARIOS">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="nome">
            <column name="NOME" />
        </property>
        <property name="email">
            <column name="EMAIL" />
        </property>
        <property name="senha">
            <column name="SENHA" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### LOCAL DO PROBLEMA

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //UIJanelaServidorCentralChat.getInstance();
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.configure("ecochat\\hibernate\\configuracoes\\hibernate.cfg.xml");
            Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(Level.OFF);

            SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory();

            Session session = factory.openSession();
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            Usuario usuario = (Usuario) session.get(Usuario.class, new Integer(2));
            System.out.println(usuario.getNome());
        } catch(HibernateException exception){
             exception.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Ops! " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        }
    }
```

### CONSULTA MONTADA PELO HIBERNATE

```
select usuario0_.ID as ID1_0_0_, usuario0_.NOME as NOME2_0_0_, usuario0_.EMAIL as EMAIL3_0_0_, usuario0_.SENHA as SENHA4_0_0_ from USUARIOS usuario0_ where usuario0_.ID=?.
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### REGISTRO NO BANCO

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sou novato na programação e não sei exatamente como utilizar o Hibernate e se está correto o que estou fazendo, se puderem por favor me dar alguma dica de como melhorar eu agradeço.

Comment: Se for necessário alguma outra informação, por favor me diga para que eu possa editar a pergunta.

Comment: Em vez de de fotos, coloque os código diretamente. Você pode ler um pouco mais em: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @LSA 
Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Amigo, se eu não entendi errado, vc esta fazendo errado no seu código, vc esta setado o código com valor errado, observe aqui: `Usuario usuario = (Usuario) session.get(Usuario.class, new Integer(1));`. E na consulta ao banco consta o id como 2

Comment: Nossa @Macario1983 verdade mesmo, obrigado pela observação, mas mesmo assim ainda não trazia o registro, eu descobri o porque estava dando o erro, estou fazendo a resposta aqui, já irei enviar.

Comment: Tudo bem, mas o primeiro erro q vi foi este.

Comment: Obrigado por ver isso, eu já corrigi lá para que não fique dúvidas quanto a isso. 
O Problema que estava tendo era algo tão não intuitivo para iniciantes como eu. Vou colocar a resposta.

Comment: Todos um dia já fomos iniciante em algo, e sempre seremos em outras, para isso, sempre use o `debug`, uma dica, tem como vc criar um arquivo `properties` para habilitar o `sql` do `hibernate ` e realizar um `debug` mais qualificado!

Comment: Essa `properties` seria a `show_sql` ? Eu sempre uso ela, muito boa, facilita demais descobrir o que está acontecendo

Comment: Nossa esse "trás" foi de doer o coração, obrigado pela correção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foi resolvido o problema da seguinte forma:

Quando fiz a configuração do `hibernate.config.xml` eu usei na linha da url: `<property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:EcoChat</property>`essa configuração.

Porém isso estava criando um `banco de dados` chamado `EcoChat`na `raiz` do meu projeto.
Veja na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa forma, o banco que estava sendo acessado era o da raiz, porém o que eu estava inserindo registros usando a interface do `hsqldb` era um outro banco, localizado em outra pasta, veja na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa forma, eu consultava um banco, mas na verdade eu gostaria de estar acessando outro.

Para resolver o problema, alterei a configuração mostrada acima:
`<property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:EcoChat</property>`

para: 
`<property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:Bibliotecas/hsqldb/data/EcoChat</property>`

Assim consigo recuperar as informações localizadas no banco mais interno.